# A question on $g$-function

Tags: general-topology

A $g$-function on a space $X$ with topology $\tau$ is a mapping $g: \omega \times X \to \tau$ such that $x \in g(n,x)$ for all $n \in \omega$. Moreover,
if $g$-function satisfies that $\{x\} =\cap \{g(n,x): n\in \omega\}$ and if $y \in g(n,x)$ then $x \in g(n,y)$ for any $x,y\in X$.

Must a space $X$ with a $g$-function have a $G_\delta$-diagonal?

thanks for your help.

Comment: @Crostul see the new vision

Comment: Now you have to write what you have tried to solve this exercize.

Comment: I have not checked the details, but you could try to consider $$U_n = \{ (x,y) \in X^2 : x \in g(n,y) \}$$ try to show that these are open, and that $\bigcap_n U_n = $ the diagonal.

Comment: @Crostul How can I show that $U_n$ is open?